# LoopBack this object is undefined in custom validation

Tags: node.js, loopbackjs

I am trying to use a custom validator in a sample project in loopback. According to [loopback validate documentation](https://apidocs.strongloop.com/loopback-datasource-juggler/#validatable-validate) I should be able to use the `this` keyword to access the JSON data from the post, however, when trying it (in the example below). I get an error telling me that the `this` is undefined (and indeed the `console.log(this)` output prints `undefined`.

```
module.exports = function(Quote) {    
  Quote.validatesLengthOf('content', { min:10, message:"Code is too short"});
    Quote.validate('content', (err) => {
    console.log(this);
    if (this.content.indexOf('testing') != -1) return err();

    }, {message:'Cannot contain the word testing'});
};
```

What would be the correct way to access the input data?

My  versions are:

```
$ lb --version
4.2.0 (generator-loopback@5.8.1 loopback-workspace@4.3.0)
$ node --version
v6.9.1
```

Answer (score 1):

This is probably happening because you are using arrow functions. Arrow functions do not have their own 'this' and hence it is undefined when you print it to console.